# Customize DOM in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I use ng-repeat to display films on my site. This is how the code looks like:

```html
<div ng-model="film" ng-repeat="film in allFilms" style="float:left;">
        <div layout-margin ng-init="defaultStyleFilm = {'width':filmWidth,'height':filmHeight,'background-size':backgroundSize}"
             ng-mouseenter="defaultStyleFilm = {'width':filmWidth,'height':filmHeight, 'background-size':backgroundSize,
              'transform':'scale(1.05)'}; customize();"
             ng-mouseleave="defaultStyleFilm = {'width':filmWidth,'height':filmHeight, 'background-size':backgroundSize,
              'transform':'scale(1.0)','transition':'transform 150ms linear'}"
             ng-style="defaultStyleFilm"
             ng-click="detailView($index)"
             style="
                background-image: url(img/general/bluray_frame_big.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                ">

            <img ng-src="img/covers/{{film.cover}}" alt="cover-problem" ng-style="{'width':filmCoverWidth,'height':filmCoverHeight,
            'margin-top':filmCoverMarginTop,'margin-left':filmCoverMarginLeft}"/>

        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;"><h3 ng-style="{'font-size':filmTitelFontSize}">{{film.titel}}</h3></div>

    </div>
```

I want to be able to customize the look (DOM) of all -but- also just of one element in my ng-repeat.
For example:
I would like to add a new div-container just next to the clicked element and present some information there. I used ng-style to play a bit around but I don't know how to modify the e.g. `<div>` style of JUST a specific object.

Hope you people understand what I mean and somebody can help me out!

Comment: As I understand, you want to modify HTML (or style?) for only one item in ng-repeat ? On what base you want to choose this element?

Comment: Wow, you really should not ng-style, but use CSS classes and make them conditional on a scope variable with ng-class.